# Marionette - Is there a better way to get the itemViewContainer of a compositeView

Tags: marionette

I would like to be able to hide and show a compositeView's itemViewContainer, but I feel like it could be done better.

Here is my code:

```
MyCompView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // ITEM VIEW
    itemView: MyView,

    // ITEM VIEW CONTAINER
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',

    // EVENTS
    events: {
        'click #table-toggle': 'onToggleClick'
    },

    onToggleClick: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.toggle();
    },
    // Toggle
    toggle: function(){
        this.$(this.itemViewContainer).toggle();
    }
```

Here is the template for MyCompView

```
<script id='MyCompView-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
<div>
    <span id='heading-container' style="font-weight:bold">Some name</span>
    <a id='table-toggle' href="#">[-]</a>
</div>

<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option, which really isn't any better in this example, is to use the `ui` configuration for the view:

```
MyCompView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    // ITEM VIEW
    itemView: MyView,

    // ITEM VIEW CONTAINER
    itemViewContainer: 'tbody',



    // UI configuration to cache selectors
    // -----------------------------------
    ui: {
      table: "tbody"
    }


    // EVENTS
    events: {
        'click #table-toggle': 'onToggleClick'
    },

    onToggleClick: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.toggle();
    },
    // Toggle
    toggle: function(){
        this.ui.table.toggle();
    }
}
```

If you're re-using the same selector multiple times in your code, this can help to reduce duplication. In your case, though, it is directly duplicating the itemViewContainer's selector so I don't really think it's much better.

Answer (score 2):

It is available, just as the `el`/`$el` property, as `this.$itemViewContainer`. However, it seems to be some kind of a race condition here somewhere, even trying to access `this.$itemViewContainer` after rendering is done can sometimes fail.

Falling back to reselecting it for now.